# Custom Http Service in Camunda Task List

Tags: camunda

I would like to inject a custom http service in my embedded task form application.

Herewith is the code snippet:

```
<script cam-script type="text/form-script">
  inject([ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {

    // Custom service call
    $http.get('http://localhost:8888/books/1').then(function(response){
        alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    });

  });
}]);
```

When the form loads the http://localhost:8888/books/1 isn't invoked and I don't know why.

Comment: Found the following error message: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8888/books/1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403. Now just to figure out how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else running into the same issue here is the code snippet that made debugging a bit easier:

```
<script cam-script type="text/form-script">

debugger;

inject([ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {


    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/books/1'
    }).then(
        function successCallback(response)
        {
            alert('SUCCESS :-) ' + angular.toJson(response.data));
            $scope.data = response.data
        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
            alert('FAILED :-( ' + response.status);
        });

     });
}]);

</script>
```

As for the solution, I had to enable CORS on the server that was receiving the request. See https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/